# How can I group a list of strings by another list of strings using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, pandas-groupby, python-3.7

I have two lists:

**List 1**

```
filenames = ['K853.Z', 'K853.N', 'K853.E', 'K400.Z', 'K400.N', 'K400.E']
```

**List 2**

```
l = ['K853', 'K400']
```

I want to iterate through the `filenames` list and group the strings by the `l` list.

I've tried the below:

```
for name in filenames:
    for i in l:
        if i in name:
            print(name)
```

But this just prints the first list. I've seen the `Pandas` `groupby` method but I can't figure out how to utilize it in this case.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just use a list generator like this:

```
new = [[name for name in filenames if(name.startswith(prefix))] for prefix in l]
```

This would provide you with a list of list, where for each index of l you would get a list of files with its prefix at the same index in the new list.

Comment: In your case this would yield [['K853.Z', 'K853.N', 'K853.E'], ['K400.Z', 'K400.N', 'K400.E']]

Comment: What if there is something infront of the 'prefix', like so: `string.K853.Z`

Comment: per definition of prefix, this would then be part of the prefix. But then you would have to maybe rethink your strategy and/or use a `contains()` method